# What does 'bombasity' mean?

Tags: meaning

I came aross the word *bombasity* here: http://craigmod.com/journal/digital_physical/

> I would argue, however, that for Christo and Jeanne-Claude, the book simply formalized much of what they already knew. Their work benches were covered in schematics, file cabinets filled with correspondence between farmers and governments and architects and textile manufacturers and engineers. In other words — to them the magnitude and grandiose nature of their work was present all around their home, their work space. It manifest physically in those files and papers and cabinets. For them, a monster book like this didn’t illuminate the enormity of their undertaking — they were aware of The Umbrellas’ bombasity every time they opened their studio door.

But don't know what it means. I searched on Google and only found people using it but no explanations, even here: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bombasity

Can somebody give some explanation about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a nonce word which is the noun described by the adjective *bombastic*:

> **bombastic** *adjective*
>   high-sounding but with little meaning; inflated:
>      *bombastic rhetoric
>
>      bombastic music that drowned out what anyone was saying*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bombastic)

Thus it has a similar meaning (and construction) to ***pomposity***.

Answer (score -5):

One who feels their words are the truth with no knowledge of what they're talking about!

Comment: Even if that were accurate, it would refer to _bombastic_ not _bombasity_. In any case, when giving a definition please include a dictionary entry that backs you up.